# QR code decoder

Tags: code-golf

Your mission is not so simple. You have to write a program that decodes QR-codes.

There are some things that are not permitted:

- Making web requests (except https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCUJT.png or https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXUcd.jpg)
- Using any QR code processing library (Or using any external library to do this)
- Image processing libraries should not be be used to do anything other than loading image, determining its size and reading single pixels from it
- Using built-in functions to read QR codes
- Brute forcing

If you use any external files (except QR code file and language libraries), the byte count of those files will be added to your code.

Other rules:

- Program must be able to read any valid QR code (No error correction is required). You can assume that the maximum size of QR-Code is 10000 pixels.
- QR code colors are black and white. ((0, 0, 0) and (255, 255, 255) in RGB. Alpha channel is not used, so your program can ignore it.
- Image file must be saved as PNG or loaded from https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXUcd.jpg or https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCUJT.png runtime. (And tricks like using raw txt file with .png file extension are prohibited)
- QR code decoded content must be outputted to stdout. If your language does not allow this, you can save it to file named `qrcode.txt`.
- QR-code format is normal qr-code (not any modification like micro QR code)

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code wins

An example file is here: http://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?color=000000&bgcolor=FFFFFF&data=http%3A%2F%2Fcodegolf.stackexchange.com&qzone=1&margin=0&size=400x400&ecc=L

[image: QR code]

Comment: Can we get the Imgur URL for free in our submissions? URL shorteners could be used, and it would be unfair if that would break ties.

Comment: http://imgur.com/JUQbo8M

Comment: Hmm... I forgot that other web requests are disallowed, so URL shorteners actually don't matter here.

Comment: "Using language that haves built-in functionality to read QR codes" so I can't even use the language if I omit all that built-in functionality?

Comment: No, I mean if yout language have something like `decode_qr_code(image)` you can not use that

Comment: Does it matter what input format we use?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: This question needs more information: Which QR code version do we use (all of them?)? Do we need to flip around the diagonal if we can't decode? Will we always have a nice QR-only picture, or will we need to search through a picture that contains a QR code? Which encodings should we support?  Will we need to support error handling/error handling modes?

Comment: "Program must be able to read any valid QR code ... You can assume that maximium size of qrcode is 10000 (100*100) pixels." No, you do not need to flip. qrcode is always as "nice" as example image. Binary (8-bit) encoding. No error handling needed.

Comment: This is going to be difficult af [spec, iso or whatever is called](http://raidenii.net/files/datasheets/misc/qr_code.pdf)

Comment: This may help somebody: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KA8hDldvfv0

Comment: Which QR code version/specification do we use? Can we assume that 1 pixel in image = 1 pixel in code or do we have to find out the scale first?

Comment: If version means size, then only size is limited. No, you have to scale.

Comment: This was helpful http://blog.qartis.com/decoding-small-qr-codes-by-hand/

Comment: Could you define "Brute-forcing"? I don't understand it in the context. Unless I check every pixel, I don't see how I could understand the qr code....

Comment: As it stands the challenge does not say what counts as a valid QR-Code, nor how they are decoded. As challenges should be self-contained, please add these informations.